# Compilation Error: C:\Users\mhomes\AppData\Local\Temp\8\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ Line: 90

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have researched this and found a bunch of random suggestions for fixing the problem. Anyone have a solid solution or explanation on how to fix this issue? I get it on every page I try to load except my default page.

```
End Property

Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Master() As ASP.site_master
Get
Return CType(MyBase.Master,ASP.site_master)
```

Here is the exception in my exeception log:

> Source:
>   System.Web

Stack Trace

```
> Stack Trace:
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Exeception:

```
> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): C:\Users\mhomes\AppData\Local\Temp\8\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\186f450a\b5b0d34a\App_Web_orders.aspx.cdcab7d2.esarqmv5.0.vb(90): error BC30560: 'site_master' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Exception Type

```
> System.Web.HttpCompileException
```

URL

> `http://localhost:64223/orders.aspx`

I have tried:

- Cleaning Solution
- Cleaning Project
- Rebuilding Solution
- Build each project
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Repair on Visual Studio

Ideas?

Comment: `error BC30560: 'site_master' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'` - figure out where you have two things with that same name, and fix it.

Comment: Web app is a copy of another web app I just modified the back end logic not the front or pages. Other app works

Comment: Did some more research an I found something related. It appears I may not have enough VR memory. I'm running on a Virtual machine so not sure if that's affecting it or not. Has anyone else had this issue with VR machines before? Not sure if I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Is `ASP` the "root" of the namespace?  If not, you could try fully qualifying the site_master type using the full namespace name.